# What are the benefits of using a tool like Chef vs. using a makefile/shell script for deployment?

Tags: deployment, makefile, chef-infra, devops

I have heard good things about Chef, was curious about all of the benefits before I devote time to learning a new tool. Not looking to turn this into opinion thread, looking for a list of additional features it has over makefile/shell script.

Comment: There's so many Google-able feature lists, this still feels like an opinion thread (https://www.google.com/search?q=chef+features yields tons of appropriate material).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chef, and Ansible/Puppet/Salt too (collectively called CAPS), are all based on the structure of "describe the desired state of the system and the tool will make it happen".

A script or Makefile is generally a procedural system, run this, then run that, etc. That means you need to keep a mental model of system from each step to the next, and if that ever deviates from the real system (ex, a directory you are trying to set the owner of doesn't exist) your script usually breaks.

With some stuff this is easy, like `yum/apt-get install` as they are internally idempotent, you can run them every time and if the package is already installed, it just does nothing.

CAPS systems take that principle (idempotence) and apply it to all management tasks. This has for the most part resulted in less brittle configuration management as you only need to tell the tool what the end result should look like and it will take care of figuring out the delta from the current state.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit to ease reading, feel free to roll back if you find it useless.